# button onClick not working, reactjs application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two buttons that serve to open and close a sidebar menu, they recently stopped working for no reason. I tried to create new buttons, because all the rest of the code was working, when recreating they started working again, but when navigating a little more, they stopped again. Note that none works, not even a console.log

```html
<button type="button" onClick={() => console.log('okaay')}>
 <FiAlignRight size={28} color="#fff" />
</button>
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick={() => console.log('close button')}>
 <FiXCircle color="#fff" size={24} />
</button>
```

```css
.sidebar_hidden {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin-left: auto;

    svg {
      margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    }
  }

.sidebar_open {
    display: none;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;

    @media (max-width: 1023px) {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #000;
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: Did you put them into any form recently?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything on these buttons